# How to align left element inside a div with centered align

Tags: html, css

I have a css that has a `text-align: center`, as I want most of my elements centered, however there is an element that I want to be towards top left.

I could do it by changing the `margin-right: ??px`. But I feel that this is not the best approach. Is there a better way to *top left* an element inside a `text-align: center` div.

`dropbox` contains the `text-align: center`. I want the `img` to be *top left*.

```css
img {
  text-align: left;/*(does not work)*/
  margin-right: 95px;/*(works but dont think is the best approach)*/
}

.dropbox {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropBox">
  <img src="pdf.jpg" id="pdf"/><br>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using dropBox in html and in css you wrote dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the image a `block` element - nothing else necessary  (see below)

```css
img {
  display: block;
}

.dropBox {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropBox">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" id="pdf"><br>
  some more text<br>
  some more text<br>
  some more text<br>
  some more text<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks yes that did help. however, some inputs are now further down because of the img block.

Comment: what do you mean by "inputs"?

Comment: the img block takes up 100% width, so the subsequent elements will be below that. If you don't want that, you can assign the image  `position:absolute` and `width` and `height` settings, and assign `position:relative` to its parent `.dropBox`. This will place the image into the upper left corner, but it might overlap other elements that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with position attribute for top and left to the image.

```
img {
       position:absolute; 
      top : 15px;
      left : 15px;
    }

    .dropbox {
      text-align: center;
      position : relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. You had the dropbox class in your HTML spelled incorrectly.

```css
.leftAlign {
  text-align: left;
}

.dropbox {
  width: 300px; /* only for demo */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropbox">
  <p class="leftAlign">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" id="pdf">
  </p>
  <p>Dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Its right on the code but i miss typed when writing here thanks for noticing

Answer (score -1):

`.dropBox :not(img) {
    text-align:center;
}`

What happens is everything inside `.dropBox` will be centered as originally intended but "not" `img` elements.

This method will not affect other elements or the layout from using `display` or `position` as others suggest.

Answer (score -2):

Try only align without text:

```
<img align="left">
```

Comment: That will be hard to pick up when reviewing code, say when they want to change the aligning.  It's better to use CSS for styling.

Comment: He can put thath in his css
img {
align: left;
}

Comment: which your example doesn't show.  the OP might not *know* they can put it in their CSS.

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I didnt know that.